# Multi-level generic type constraints in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I'm not sure if the title of the question is right but assuming we have 2 generic structs `Foo` and `Bar` defined below.

```
// Foo
struct Foo<T> {
}

// Bar
struct Bar<U: Codable> {
}
```

I would like to create an extension on `Foo` where `T` is constrained to be equal to `Bar` while maintaining the constraint that `Bar.U` conforms to `Codable`.

Basically, how can I do something like the following?

```
extension Foo where T == Bar<U: Codable> {
}
```

The above doesn't compile. Using a concrete type that conforms to `Codable` (`extension Foo where T == Bar<String>`) works but then, that limits the extension to only one concrete type of `Codable`.

I will appreciate any help/insights. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you can do it using a protocol with associated type:

```
struct Foo<T> { }

protocol BarProtocol {
     associatedtype U: Codable
}

struct Bar<U: Codable>: BarProtocol {

}

// Now this works
extension Foo where T: BarProtocol {
    // T.U can be of any type that implements Codable
}
```

---

Edit - Changed to T: BarProtocol, thanks Marcel!

Comment: `T == BarProtocol` should probably be `T: BarProtocol`, otherwise everything defined in the extension will only be accessible on `Foo<BarProtocol>` and not on for example `Foo<Bar<String>>`. Apart from that, I agree that this is the "swiftiest" way of solving the problem.